# Inserting at head of linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

Im trying to insert a node at the head of a linked list, and I'm not exactly sure why this function isn't working. I thought it was a fairly simple task, but I seem to be missing something here. I've also included my structs and a portion of main so you can get a clearer understanding of the code. Thanks

```
typedef struct node
{
  struct node *next;
  int data;
} node;

typedef struct LinkedList
{
  node *head;
  node *tail;
} LinkedList;

LinkedList *create_list(void)
{
  return calloc(1, sizeof(LinkedList));
}

node *create_node(int data)
{
  node *ptr = calloc(1, sizeof(node));
  ptr->data = data;

  return ptr;
}

void head_insert(LinkedList *list, int data) // problem
{
  node *newHead = create_node(data);
  newHead->next = list->head;
}

void print_list_helper(node *head)
{
  if (head == NULL)
    return;
  printf("%d%c", head->data, (head->next == NULL) ? '\n' : ' ');
  print_list_helper(head->next);
}

void print_list(LinkedList *list)
{
  if (list == NULL || list->head == NULL)
    return;
  print_list_helper(list->head);
}

int main(void)
{
  LinkedList *list = create_list();
  head_insert(list, 8);
  print_list(list); // print linked list function

  return 0;
}
```

So I created a new Node, and set node->next to the head of the list. Im not sure what else im missing here. I have another function that prints the lists, thats why the function is void.

Comment: `node *newHead = create_node(data); newHead->next = list->head;`. What do you think happens to `newHead` once the function ends? It's gone. No one/variable has any reference to it any longer. You need to return the new head to the caller one way or another.

Comment: How does the code that called `head_insert()` know about the new node which is now the head of the list?  You've not changed `list->head`, have you?  You should, though, shouldn't you?  This is a very common problem with list handling code.  It is actually simpler to resolve since you have the `LinkedList` structure.  Often, people just use pointers to `node` and then you have to work harder.

Comment: First time in `head_insert()`, `list->head`  is a problem as `head == NULL`.

Comment: You may benefit from [Singly Linked List of Integers (example)](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines at the end of your `head_insert()` function definition:

```
if (list->head == NULL)
{
    list->tail = newHead;
}
list->head = newHead;
```

In your function, after adding new node at head the struct LinkedList still pointed to the previous head. You should change that head to the newly inserted head. And if there was no nodes in the list you should also set the newly created head
Here is the full function.

```
void head_insert(LinkedList *list, int data)
{
  node *newHead = create_node(data);
  newHead->next = list->head;
  if (list->head == NULL)
  {
    list->tail = newHead;
  }
  list->head = newHead;
}
```

Comment: Since a `node *tail;` pointer is used, you must check if `list->head` is `NULL` before adding the node and set `list->head = list->tail = newHead;` in that case to initialize the `tail` pointer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, I didn't notice that. But tail shouldn't be modified all the time. It should be modified only if there was no nodes as head/tail. Because we are only inserting at first position. After the first insertion the tail will always be the same. I have modified my code.

Comment: I'd write the code as `if (list->tail == NULL) list->tail = newHead;`, testing and assigning to the same member, rather than testing `head` and assigning to `tail`.  It feels more consistent.  The result is the same, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If we do that and somehow the tail becomes null, the next insertion will make the newly inserted node as tail and result in inconsistency. Otherwise you should check if tail is null and if it is you should loop through the list and add the last element as tail.

Comment: You can think of it this way. The `tail` pointer always points to the last node in the list. This allows O(1) insertions at the end without having to iterate over the list. When the first node is inserted, both `head` and `tail` point to the same node. When then next node is added, you do `tail->next = newnode; tail = newnode;` When adding a new head, if `head` isn't `NULL`, it's just `newnode->next = head; head = newnode;` In that case, `tail` isn't changed. Take a look at the link in my comment under the original question.

Comment: How would `tail` suddenly become `NULL`?  It shouldn't be possible — if it happens, it's a bug.  The tail can only be null when the list is empty.  If there are one or more elements in the list, neither the head nor the tail can be null.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Yes Tail won't be changed if coded properly.